# How to post json data of multidimentional array using curl?

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, multidimensional-array

My code is

```
$urltopost = "http://example.com/webservice/service.php";
$datatopost = array (0 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),1 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),2 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),3 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'));
$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($datatopost));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
```

i am not getting this json to my url ...

Comment: In your `service.php`, did you have header set to accept json data? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18867369/2324206

Comment: can you print json_encode($datatopost)

Answer (score 1):

finally got the solution here it is. and it's working with multidimentional array.

```
$urltopost = "http://example.com/webservice/service.php";
$datatopost = array (0 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),1 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),2 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),3 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'));
$post_data = array('data' => serialize($datatopost));

$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(unserialize($returndata));
```

service.php code

```
$temp = unserialize($_POST['data']);
echo serialize($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:  (put your json string length into content-length)

```
$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://api.local/rest/users');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: you are sennding simple one dimentional array. i am trying post multidimentional array

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to post raw JSON data on `service.php`. 
Passing raw JSON data doesn't populate `$_POST` array. On `service.php` page you need to catch passed data from php ***stdin*** stream like shown below:

```
$fp = fopen("php://input", "r");
$data = stream_get_contents($fp);
$decoded_json_data = json_decode($data);

var_dump($decoded_json_data);
```

Also there is another approach which lets you to populate `$_POST` array:

```
    $urltopost = "http://example.com/webservice/service.php";
    $datatopost = array (0 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),1 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),2 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'),3 =>array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'));
    $data_string = http_build_query(['json' => json_encode($datatopost)]);

    $ch = curl_init($urltopost);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Content-Length: '.strlen($data_string)]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $returndata = curl_exec($ch);
```

Now, on `service.php` page you can access your multidimensional array in the following way:

```
if (isset($_POST['json'])){
    $data = json_decode($_POST['json']);
}
```

Comment: removed json_encode but showing me error  "Array to string conversion"

Comment: @SatejInfotech, I apologise. Yes, let the `json_encode` remain

Comment: its ok , can we post multidimentional array with curl ?? if yes how ??

Comment: what gives you `var_dump($decoded_json_data);` when dealing with the above approach ? Or, maybe, you wanted to work only with `$_POST` array?

Comment: var_dump($decoded_json_data); gives nothing. its empty.

Comment: @SatejInfotech, check the second approach